# Admob background color

Tags: android, android-layout, admob

I have read the other Q&A about background colors with Admob, and concur with the answers there. Alone, even the 'standard' ads look weird and I can't get them to look the way I want.

This is my layout section:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
[..]
    <com.google.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adViewMain"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#6D0504"
        ads:background="#6D0504"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="a…xxxxx"
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="false" />
[..]
```

And in the OnCreate section of the activity:

```
    AdView adview = (AdView)findViewById(R.id.adViewMain);
    AdMobAdapterExtras extras = new AdMobAdapterExtras()
    .addExtra("color_bg", "6D0504")
    .addExtra("color_bg_top", "6D0504")
    .addExtra("color_border", "6D0504")
    .addExtra("color_link", "000080")
    .addExtra("color_text", "808080")
    .addExtra("color_url", "008000");

    AdRequest adreq = new AdRequest();
    adreq.setNetworkExtras(extras);
    adview.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#6D0504"));
    adview.loadAd(adreq);
```

Although I am shooting with fully loaded cannons (setting the BG color wherever possible and trying my best to avoid borders), it seems impossible for me to achieve any change of colors at any of the displayed ads.

To at least achieve /something/, I went to the AdMob config panel and tried to force the color settings from there, but it only allows to set the background color and forces on me an ugly border and a 'glossy' effect which looks nothing but strange on a gradient background!

Even with the 'brute force' attempt of setting the colors directly in the admin panel, sometimes the ads that display "kind of" the way they are supposed to according to my settings still also show with the standard black background and blue borders for whatever reason.

Did I miss something, or is the functionality really that buggy or inconsistent? Just curious if I can fix that or have to wait for an update.

Answer (score 2):

You are correctly setting the color parameters via `AdmobAdapterExtras`, but these only apply for AdMob text ads for now, not AdSense backfill text ads.  There currently is not a way to change the colors of these ads.

To verify that AdMob text ad colors work, you could create your own AdMob text House Ad, and verify that these background colors are being used.

Comment: So if I never saw any ad displayed in my app with the color I set with AdmobAdapterExtras, does that mean the number of such ads is so little compared with others that most of the time, none of them will be displayed? (if not, I might just disable all others for the sake of the visual appearance of my app … but then, if this would result in no ads being displayed I wouldn't really be satisfied as well ;-))

Comment: Lately I haven't seen too many AdMob text ads.  They are either image ads, or the AdSense backfill ads which have a blue border around them.